# Bash function squashing output from 'jobs' while job is paused

Tags: linux, bash, unix, vim, command-line

```
# allow CTRL-Q and CTRL-S keybindings
vim() {
  (
    # No ttyctl, so we need to save and then restore terminal settings
    # osx users, use stty -g
    local STTYOPTS="$(stty --save 2> /dev/null)"
    trap "stty $STTYOPTS" EXIT
    stty stop '' start '' -ixoff
    command vim "$@"
  )
}
```

I'm using the above shell function to temporarily change stty options so that CTRL-Q and CTRL-S can function as keybinds in vim.

This works nicely, but as a side-effect I can no longer see which file corresponds to a background job when I pause vim with CTRL-Z. I frequently work with multiple sessions in the background and it would be really handy to be able to see which job is which again.

Current output from jobs with a background task:

```
root@rock64:~# jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 ( local STTYOPTS="$(stty --save 2> /dev/null)"; trap "stty $STTYOPTS" EXIT; stty stop '' start '' -ixoff; command vim "$@" )
root@rock64:~#
```

Unwrapped output like this would be ideal:

```
root@rock64:~# jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 vim .bashrc
root@rock64:~#
```

Is there a different way to achieve the same effect (temporarily changing STTY options with restore on job completion) without squashing the background jobs listing?

I'm running Bash 4.4.x at the moment but I could easily compile a newer version if needed.

Comment: What happens if you use `exec command vim "$@"`?

Comment: Well, nothing as "command" isn't something that exec can interact with. If you were to `exec vim "$@"` from the interactive shell it would run vim and then terminate your session on exit.

If you're talking about running exec vim "$@" from within an anonymous subshell I'll go give that a shot and see how it behaves, that would be a great solution if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately using exec doesn't improve on things. The entire anonymous subshell block is interrupted when you suspend vim (even with exec used) so the command line output from 'jobs' is still garbage. I think you could make an alias plus a function work if you wrapped the function call in an anonymous subshell but you'd still end up with garbage all over the process command line. A wrapper script (with or without an alias) seems like the cleanest way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

I went ahead and improved the wrapper to look for the next real vim in the path if it's run as a symlink called 'vim' in the user path. This avoids needing to use an alias pointing 'vim' at vimwrapper.sh and transparently forwards 'vim' calls to the actual vim binary. I think this is basically complete now.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# vimwrapper.sh:  Wrapper script to enable use of CTRL-Q/S keybinds in Vim
#
# Using a wrapper script avoids clobbering the editor command line with an
# anonymous subshell that's hard to read when vim is suspended with ^Z. We need
# the scope of the subshell to trap our trap (aaayyyyy) and keep the stty magic
# out of our interactive environment's namespace.  The wrapper script just
# makes background jobs look sane if you interrupt vim with CTRL-Z.

# set -x

case $(basename "$0") in
  "vim")
    # Check if we're shadowing real vim by existing earlier in the path as a
    # symlink and call it directly if so. This lets us symlink vimwrapper.sh to
    # "$HOME/bin/vim", munge "$HOME:/bin" onto the beginning of the path and
    # transparently wrap calls to 'vim' without our script going recursive.

    for _v in $(which -a "vim"); do
      # I refuse to fork myself. You know what, fork you too.
      [[ $(realpath "$_v") == $(realpath "$0") ]] && continue
      #printf "found real vim in path at '%s'\n" "$(realpath $_v)"
      cmd="$_v" && break
    done

    if [[ -z "$cmd" ]]; then
      echo "$(basename $0): Unable to find real vim in path"
      exit 1
    fi
    ;;
  *)
    cmd="vim"
    ;;
esac

STTYOPTS="$(stty --save 2> /dev/null)"
trap "stty $STTYOPTS" EXIT
stty stop '' start '' -ixoff
command "$cmd" "$@"
```

---

Original post:

After playing with this for a while today I think I've got a decent solution. A subshell is necessary to scope/contain the stty parameter changes and the vim process that we want effected by them, but it doesn't have to be an anonymous function in the main shell environment.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# vimwrapper.sh:  Wrapper script to enable use of CTRL-Q/S keybinds in Vim
#                 For best results bind 'alias vim="/path/to/vimwrapper.sh"
#
# Using a wrapper and alias avoids clobbering the editor command line with an
# anonymous subshell that's hard to read when vim is suspended with ^Z. We need
# the scope of the subshell to trap our trap (aaayyyyy) and keep the stty magic
# out of our interactive environment's namespace.  The wrapper script just
# makes background jobs look sane if you interrupt vim with CTRL-Z.

# We'll be paranoid and make sure our wrapper script isn't the target of the
# 'command vim' call that comes next.
if [[ $(realpath $(basename "$0")) == $(realpath $(which vim)) ]]; then
  echo "$0: I refuse to fork myself. You know what, fork you too."
else
  # Save stty state and restore on exit.
  STTYOPTS="$(stty --save 2> /dev/null)"
  trap "stty $STTYOPTS" EXIT
  stty stop '' start '' -ixoff

  command vim "$*"
fi

exit 0
```

Binding a call to the wrapper script as `alias vim="~/foo/vimwrapper.sh"` takes care of everything nicely:

```
root@rock64:~/bin# vim vim.sh 


[1]+  Stopped                 ~/bin/vim.sh vim.sh
```

It's possible to symlink vimwrapper.sh as 'vim' somewhere in the path provided its location has a lower priority than real vim's too. I added a check for that so it doesn't go recursive by accident. I'll probably expand that a little bit so the script can shadow the real vim in the path and figure out which is the right command to call by looking at `which -a vim` and picking the next entry that isn't itself.

Thanks @Jason for pointing me in the right direction, I really appreciate it.

Comment: +1 for telling me to go fork myself.  I would just change `command vim "$*"` to `command vim "$@"`.  Using the `*` will pass all of the arguments as one single argument.

Answer (score 1):

So what I am suggesting in the comment is difficult to convey without better code formatting.  I am simply suggesting removing the surrounding `(` and `)`. Additionally, the RETURN trap would need to be removed, so I just made a second function that, when `return` is called, we jump back to the original function and remove the trap.

```
runvim() {
    local STTYOPTS="$(stty --save 2> /dev/null)"
    trap "stty $STTYOPTS" RETURN # This may need to be changed to RETURN
    stty stop '' start '' -ixoff
    command vim "$@"
}

# allow CTRL-Q and CTRL-S keybindings
vim() {
    # No ttyctl, so we need to save and then restore terminal settings
    # osx users, use stty -g
    runvim "$@"
    trap - RETURN
}
```

Alternative

You could put this in a script called `vim` in `$HOME/bin`:

```
#!/bin/bash
STTYOPTS="$(stty --save 2> /dev/null)"
trap "stty $STTYOPTS" EXIT
stty stop '' start '' -ixoff
#/usr/bin/vim "$@" # or where ever your vim is
$( whereis vim | cut -d\  -f3) "$@"  # Here is a more generic version.
```

Then add that directory to the front of your `PATH` variable by adding `export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` to your favorite dot file.

Comment: Ahh, nice catch. It looks like that can work. Thinking about when to dump and save stty options made me notice that multiple calls to my vim() function can clobber them anyway if I exit my vim processes in the wrong order too. I'll run with the function minus the subshell while I figure out a way to save stty state more reliably. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @KorbenDallas Yes.  What you are doing is similar to calling a script called vim containing the body of function (minus the `(` and `)` ) because it is launching its own shell.  Now that I think of it, that could be an alternative solution to this problem.  You could put the meat of this into a little script that either sits in your `PATH` in front of the actual `vim` binary or you make an alias to it.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to need to do that. Messing with traps without a subshell clobbers traps for the entire shell session. I setup tests that just did something like `printf "\n\nhi mom!\n\n"` as a trap for RETURN and it fires every time a subshell runs. I think an actual wrapper script is probably the way to go, then I can rely on the scope of the wrapper script (a subshell of the main bash process) to contain the traps. Thanks, this gives me something to go on!

Comment: @KorbenDallas You have a point there.  I edited the original solution with a possible work around for that.  I didn't test it, but it should be close.  `trap -` will remove a trap.

Comment: Thanks for getting me started thinking about this today, I posted a solution that I'm reasonably happy with below. Splitting the original function off into its own script solves all of the namespace issues and aliasing the function to 'vim' makes it accessible.

You need to be careful shadowing real vim with the script as calling "vim" without an explicit path can go recursive. I added a check for that in case anyone drops vimwrapper.sh into their path as "vim" but I think I'll add some logic to iterate over `which -a vim` and call the first one that isn't the wrapper itself. Thanks!